# JQuery: how to determine if the cursor is in the 'focus' or 'select' state?

Tags: jquery, select, focus

I used to move cursor into an `<input>` field with the following statements:

```
$('#id').focus();
$('#id').select();
```

Now, how do I detect if the cursor is currently in the `focus` or `select` state?

Comment: `$('#id').focus(function(){ alert("focused"); });`?

Comment: What I expect is something like `$('#id').is(':focus');` but this command doesn't distinguish between `focus` and `select`.

Comment: Can you describe why you need to distinguish between both methods? And why are you using both methods not just a specific one?

Comment: This is for a bunch of fast-typing entry clerks. They only use arrow keys and number keys. When the cursor is in the `select` state, pressing left or right arrow key would result in jumping to the previous or next input field. If the cursor is in the `focus` state, left or right arrow would result in cursor moving in the data string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/1tjqb0ns/) what you are looking for?

```
if($el.is(':focus')) {
    console.log('focus');
}
if(window.getSelection().toString() === $el.val()) {
    console.log('selected');
}
```